# Creating sections within UICollectionView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uicollectionview

In my controller, I parse data from a JSON array and use it to populate a collection view.  The code below successfully loads and displays the data, but fails to create individual sections.

As such, how do I modify the code to create sections for each object within the array.  For example, if my array has a count of 50 urls, how do I create one section for each?

```
     let lastItem = self.photos.count
     self.photos.addObjectsFromArray(photoInfos)

     let indexPaths = (lastItem..<self.photos.count).map { NSIndexPath(forItem: $0, inSection: 0) }

     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    self.collectionView!.insertItemsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths)
                }
```

Comment: use table for this its more easy for that

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time the apps use one section and many items in this section so that's why it may be a bit harder to find how to do your way.

It's all about how you use this 2 functions of the datasource:

```
func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return self.items.count
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}
```

Normally you return 1 section and the array count in the numberOfItemsInSection, but if you switch them you would have exactly what you want.

Comment: This makes sense, but when I add the code, I get the following runtime error which makes me think that I need to adjust the way I insert the objects.  Just not sure how.                                                                                                                  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to insert item 1 into section 0, but there are only 1 items in section 0 after the update'

Comment: Oh. You don't need the self.collectionView!.insertItemsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths) anymore. Just do a self.collectionView!.reloadData

Comment: Is it better to use insertItemsAtIndexPath(indexPaths) because it adds new items rather than reloading the entire collection view?

Comment: Reloading the entire collectionView is fine. You use insert when you want to animate adding some cells into view.

Answer (score 1):

here is my code is in Objective-C, I hope it'll helpful to you.
Here `HeaderView` is sub class of `UICollectionReusableView`.
Where you can set view as you like.

```
-(CGSize) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout referenceSizeForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return CGSizeMake(320.0f, 32.0f);
}

-(UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    HeaderView *view=(HeaderView *)[historyCollection dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"headerView" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSArray *viewsToRemove = [view subviews];
    for (UIView *v in viewsToRemove) {
        [v removeFromSuperview];
    }
    view.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    self.month = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 5, 320, 21)];
    self.month.text =[[monthList objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] uppercaseString];
    self.month.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    self.month.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17];
    [view addSubview:self.month];

    return view;
}
- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    if (section == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (section == 1) {
        return 40.0;
    }
    else  {
        return 50;
    }
}
```

Comment: Here, HeaderView should be subclass of UICollectionReusableView.

Comment: Thanks for sending. This code more or less sets up the collection view display on the storyboard.  My layout/display is fine, but I'd like to put each item in its own section.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that worked for me
create the header cell. To do which I created a custom cell class and a nib to do the customization of the cell in the graphic editor

In viewDidLoad

```
self.collectionView?.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "KlosetCollectionHeaderViewCell", bundle: nil), forSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "HeaderCell")
```

Then you add the delegate function

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> KlosetCollectionHeaderViewCell {   
println("entring viewforsuppplementaryElementofKind")
var headerCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(kind, withReuseIdentifier: "HeaderCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? KlosetCollectionHeaderViewCell
return headerCell!
}
```

This will put the HeaderCell in the `SectionView` of the `PFCollectionView`
The controls that show in the cell you add them to the xib file as well as the outlets and actions